# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Bllim\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider'

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a newbie in Laravel. I just cloned my co-worker git and try to `php artisan list` but it gives me error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Bllim\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider' not found in /Users/path-to-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157
```

I can't find any documentations about this error and search results don't really help.
Any of you ever met this problem and care to help me fix this? Thank you.

Comment: You should try some basic debugging here. An error of this variety usually means that is a bad file path reference, file permission, issue, or something of that ilk. Nothing we can do to really help with what you have shown in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking your coworker would be a first good step :)

That said, the error you're getting indicates that PHP can't find or autoload a Laravel Service provider class.  If your coworker is following Laravel best practices, you should be able to fix this by running the following command from your root project directory (or the directory with a `composer.json` file)

```
$ composer install
or ...
$ composer.phhar install
```

The format of the command (`phar` or no `phar`) will depend on how you've [installed composer](https://getcomposer.org/), the dependency/package manager used in Laravel.

Comment: I run `composer update` but it give me memory error (I use OS X). I modified memory limit in php.ini to 1024M and run `composer update` and it worked. Basically I need to run `composer update` everytime I modify `composer.json`